# Getting Error like "git error: "index file is too small"

Tags: git

I had to re-install the OS (Windows 7 x64), everything related to the project was on another partition so my projects remained. Among the applications that I needed to install was also git but after I tried to see what is the status of the project (`git status`) the following exceptions occurred:

```
error: index file .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e 4.idx is too small

error: index file .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e
4.idx is too small

error: index file .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e
4.idx is too small

error: index file .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e
4.idx is too small

warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-dc512716779f21b39f70fea9afcb5baa36ea872
d.pack cannot be accessed

error: index file .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e
4.idx is too small
```

fatal: unable to read tree 30cda07e931a7c9f3b1e3383c18efa10b2523c67

This is a first one for me. I was wondering whether somebody else encountered something similar and which was the solution for it.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the old and new version of git?

Comment: good question. The new version is 1.8.1.msysgit.1. The old one...no idea. Is there a way to find that out?

Comment: I experienced this after tar'ing up a repo on a Mac and unpacking it on a Linux system.. both systems are using git 2.20.1, although the Mac says "(Apple Git-117)" after the version. It's possible there was file corruption on the Mac side.  The `repack` suggestion resolved it for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the index for your pack file is corrupt. If you're sure that you haven't run out of disk space you can delete the index file and recreate it with:

```
git index-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-d3325f684a4eca22c0c168d7c63119da147865e4.pack
```

Note that it's extremely rare to have to do something like this so you should treat the errors as a sign of possible file system corruption. You may want to wipe everything and restore from backup.

Comment: I spitted out some errors that the index pack is not finishing with the .pack extension.

Comment: @user503413: Sorry, my mistake; I copied the name of the index files and forgot to change the extension. I've updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: Unfortunately I re-cloned the repo, so I cannot try it again. Thank you

Comment: This approach did not work for me. I got "fatal: early EOF" in response.

Comment: @Chris: Then it is likely that you pack file is corrupt as well as the index file.

Comment: I get this message from the console:
'fatal: pack signature mismatch'
What does it mean ?

Answer (score 29):

Have you tried like

In the local repository’s config, and set `repack.usedeltabaseoffset` to false and then repacked the repository:

```
git config repack.usedeltabaseoffset false
git repack -a -d
```

Comment: This seems borrowed from here: http://joemaller.com/1283/git-error-index-file-is-too-small/. The original author has a decent explanation.

Comment: I second @patrickvacek: it's polite to give credit to the original author.

Comment: This is a better answer, it solves the problem generically.

Answer (score 3):

Using `git fsck` you *might* be able to recover your repository.

But, more likely than not, you should look around for other options, like restoring from backup, or cloning from some git remote. As part of normal git development, you should have been pushing your changes to some remote server, like your another git server or Github. If you didn't, you may have really bad day.

Comment: git fsck not working. I will reclone my repo - I was just hopping that I can do without and I can learn something new. Thank you. Can you please clarify in two words what git fsck is doing.

Comment: Two words is not a lot of words. :) Let me try anyway: filesystem check.